# How to mount a Windows 8 partition

Tags: mount, ntfs, windows-8, hibernate

I am not able to mount my Windows 8 partition. Trying to do so leads to the message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb2 at /media/josh/Windows 8: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb2" "/media/josh/Windows 8"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is hibernated. Please resume and shutdown Windows
properly, or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option, or
mount the volume read-write with the 'remove_hiberfile' mount option.

For example type on the command line:

mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sdb2 /media/josh/Windows 8
```

I know that the issue has been discussed several times on this platform (the best thread would be this one: [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)).

The problem in my case it that turning off the Windows 8 fast startup option leads to simply nothing. I get this message if I shut down normally as well as if I restart Windows 8. Therefore I am unable to use (=read & write) my partition without deleting the hiberfile everytime.

Answer (score 0):

[Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Check out the solutions in that post^, the second one especially. It's read only, but its the only way to keep fastboot and access your windows drive.

Besides that, you could use windows to create a new partition which would be shared between both operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

Linux has no good support for the newest version of NTFSv3 or v4...they work on it, but so far it's read only(stable). However it has read/write support for FAT32 and FAT32v2...so creating a partition in this formation, is the most simple solution...you should get it in read/write mode than, by mounting it with the GUI of Ubuntu.

Also make sure to only resize the data partition and than reboot with Windows 8, to let it detect the new partition size...better resize it with Partition Magic or similar tool under Windows...had some problems with a XP installation on resizing it's partition with gparted...shot the XP installation, had to reinstall it.